# Find first zero bit

Tags: php, binary

What's the easiest way to find the first zero bit with PHP?

For example, say I have an integer 47 which is 111101, how can I find out that the 5th bit is the first unset bit? This needs to work to cater for different integers.

Comment: @Elliot Lings: You're getting downvotes because you haven't shown any effort insolving the problem yourself. What approaches have you already tried and failed? Have you searched the interwebs?

Comment: I would consider [converting to binary](http://php.net/manual/en/function.decbin.php) and then having a look at it. That or some pretty shiny math equation that is beyond my math knowledge.

Comment: bitwise operators such as &?

Comment: @Mark Baker: is `&` only enough?

Comment: @zerkms You'll need `&` and `<<`, "bitwise and" and "left shift" for arbitrary integers

Comment: @x3ro: I knew it, I was wondered if there is a trick using `&` exclusively.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$value = 47;
$i = $j = 1;

while (true) {
    if (($value & $j) == 0) {
        break;
    }
    $j = $j << 1;
    $i++;
}
echo "bit $i is 0";
```

If you want to eliminate the use of $i as a counter, you can do a little bit of extra math:

```
$value = 47;
$j = 1;

while (true) {
    if (($value & $j) == 0) {
        break;
    }
    $j = $j << 1;
}
echo "bit ", (log($j) / log(2) + 1), " is 0", PHP_EOL;
```

The +1 is necessary because you're starting your binary as bit 1 rather than as bit 0

Answer (score 4):

Use `decbin` to return a string of 0 and 1.
Then, use strpos to find the first 0 caracters.

```
$str = decbin(47);
$result = strpos($str, '0');
```

Comment: Or `strcspn(sprintf('%b', 47), '0')`, though that would return `8` for `255` instead of `false` :)

Comment: Why is it that I never see anyone with rep under around 10k suggesting sprintf?

Comment: @Fluffeh For the record, I *love* `sprintf()`